# How to create a tun interface for each VPN client connection and select which IPs to go through which one?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.linux.com/learn/configure-linux-clients-connect-openvpn-server

I need to setup two VPN connections to servers A and B. I also want only selected IPs to go through A and other selected IPs to go through B. Therefore I think I need 2 tun interfaces, one for each server A and B.

The article only explains how to create a connection to one server, and everything is routed through this VPN connection, but that's not what I want.

**Is there a way to create a tun interface for each VPN connection I have and select where each IP goes through?**

Comment: The server pushes all routes, so I guess when I start the client, everything will go through it. But I need only specific IPs to go through it, and I cannot modify the server, only the client

Comment: From here: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/IgnoreRedirectGateway I know that I can make my open vpn client ignore all routes, then it's just a matter of doing manual routing. But I still need one interface for each client, because I'm gonna connect to 2 different open vpn servers